# Python loop won't exit on specific user input

Tags: python, loops

Sorry if this is a common question, but every solution I've looked up so far doesn't seem to work.

Basically, I want this loop to exit when the user enters "end" but for some reason it won't actually break the loop.

```
command = input("Enter command: ") + "\r\n"
while(True):
    print(command)
    if command == "end":
        break
    else:
        tn.write(command.encode("utf-8"))
        ret1 = tn.read_until(b"_DNE", timeout = 10)
        print(ret1)
        command = input("Enter command: ") + "\r\n"
```

If the user inputs "end" it seems like it ignores the "if" statement and just skips straight to "else"

Comment: Have you tried `command == "end\r\n"` or `command == "end\n\r\n"`?

Comment: Why are you appending `\r\n` to the end of your input string?

Comment: @ILostMySpoon looks like he's writing to a device that probably uses `\r\n` as a terminator. That said, I think the best option is probably to define a `communicate` function that looks like https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/aa7672106d93bc4079f1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to attach `\r\n` to the end of the user `input`, use `raw_input` instead

```
command = raw_input("Enter command: ")
while(True):
    print(command)
    if command.rstrip('\r\n') == "end":
        break
    else:
        tn.write(command.encode("utf-8"))
        ret1 = tn.read_until(b"_DNE", timeout = 10)
        print(ret1)
        command = raw_input("Enter command: ")
```

Comment: If the OP is using python 3 (which I think it is), `raw_input()` got renamed to `input()`

Comment: @Harpal. Ahh I see. makes sense

Comment: It worked once I changed your raw_input() back to input(), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because you add `\r\n` to your input, whenever you input `end`, the variable `command` is holding `end\r\n` as the string value, not `end`. So the if statement does not detect it when the user inputs `end`.